# How can I make Floating Action Button rotate on every click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation, floating-action-button

I want the fab to rotate each time i click on it. But after trying, i achieved the rotation effect. But the problem i'm having is that it only work once. i.e on app startup.
Please help, i'm a beginner in this.
Below is the complete code i used.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_background"
        app:fabCradleMargin="15dp"
        app:menu="@menu/app_bar_layout"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="20dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="40dp"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_generate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#1D6837"
        android:src="@drawable/generate"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:contentDescription="generate"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
        app:maxImageSize="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import static androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.animate;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton generateFab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        generateFab = findViewById(R.id.fab_generate);



        generateFab.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final OvershootInterpolator interpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
                animate(generateFab).
                        setInterpolator(interpolator).
                        setListener(null).
                        rotation(360f).
                        withLayer().
                        setDuration(300).
                        withStartAction(null).
                        start();


            }

        });
    }
}
```

Basically, I added onClickListener to my floating action button inside the onCreate method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
animate(generateFab).
    setInterpolator(interpolator).
    setListener(null).
    rotation(generateFab.getRotation() + 360f).
    withLayer().
    setDuration(300).
    withStartAction(null).
    start();
```

Notice the line `rotation(generateFab.getRotation() + 360f)`.

You rotate the view 360 degrees on the first click so this changes the view elements rotation attribute to 360, and because its already 360 (after the first rotation) it wont rotate again. So instead you want to keep adding 360 degrees to the current views rotation and it will work.

**Update:**

As per comment by @AHoneyBustard you could instead of `rotation(...)` use:

```
rotationBy(360f)
```

Comment: @Ahmed Yusuf Glad to help you can give an up vote too if you feel like it ;)

Comment: Thanks @David Kroukamp I'm new to SO, up vote not recorded publicly ;)

Comment: @Ahmed Yusuf Ah makes sense been a while since I've answered questions here so I forgot about that no worry glad to help man!

Comment: You could also use the method rotationBy(360f) which would also work and is more concise

Comment: Nice one all add it to my answer for future reference